# java methods joined by a dot

Tags: java, methods

I am wondering why do you join two methods by a dot in Java, for example the following code:

```
String driverClass =
getServletContext().getInitParameter("driverClass");
```

can some one explain what does this line mean:

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter("driverClass");
```

Above there are two methods joined by a dot, why?

Comment: `result = methodA().methodB();` is basically equivalent to `temp = methodA(); result= temp.method(B);` (where `temp` is appropriately typed to match the return type from `methodA`).

Comment: +1 Why so many down votes? We all started one day, right? If a beginner has this question, why should not ask this? He provided a clear question with sample code.

Comment: @David Hover the downvote arrow and read `This question does not show any research effort`. I'm sure some of the downvotes come from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: This is called chaining. First method returns an object and on this (returned) object the second method is called. We save a line to assign it to an variable.

Answer (score 4):

This is a shortcut to the following:

```
ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
String driverClass = servletContext.getInitParameter("driverClass");
```

...and it's called ***method chaining***.

As you can see from the snippet above, the `getServletContext()` method returns an object of type `ServletContext`.

The `ServletContext` exposes a `getInitParameter()` method, which is invoked on the returned object from `getServletContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

getServletContext() will return a object. Then you call getInitParameter("driverClass") on that object. Which youw ill save in driverClass .